# Permutation generator with filter

Tags: php, filter, generator, permutation, combinations

I am looking for PHP idea/code/algorithm which can generate this:

I have 5 char string [a-zA-Z0-9]

I want to **generate permutations with variable filter**

Filter :

1. string is "W"
2. string is a number
3. string is "T"
4. string is uppercase
5. string is "3"

---

**EDIT:**

```
<?php

$reset = fopen('list.txt', 'w');
fclose($reset);

$chars = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

$file = fopen('list.txt', 'a+');

foreach ($chars as $c0) {
    foreach ($chars as $c1) {
        foreach ($chars as $c2) {
            foreach ($chars as $c3) {
                foreach ($chars as $c4) {

                    $filter = "/[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z]/";
                    $list = $c0 . $c1 . $c2 . $c3 . $c4;

                    if (preg_match($filter, $list)) {
                        $data = $list . "\n";
                        file_put_contents('list.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php you can download this package: http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating all possible permutations and then filtering that, create generators returning the possible values for each character in the string. That'll be a lot more effective (just the static W will allow you to shrink the input size by a very large factor).

You can create a generator by wrapping your function in a simple class (to allow you to keep internal state), returning each possible token for each iteration. You then create the permutations by combining the calls to each generator and creating the possible return values.

I'd also strongly advice you to not use file_get_contents and file_put_contents for something like this. Open the file using `fopen` and then do a `fwrite()` each time you have a new permutation. Call `fclose` when all the permutations has been generated.

Comment: No, that's identical. Instead of iterating through all possible values, iterate through the valid values for each location instead.